# Nuxeo Http Link for files

Tags: cmis, apache-chemistry, nuxeo, dam

I was wondering if there's a way in nuxeo or in any other CMIS-Compatiable repository through which I can get a direct URL to files stored on it, for instance if I have a ile called a.jpg that is stored on a nuxeo server, how can I get a direct URL to that file that I can use to link to the file from a web site or directly access through the internet without authentication or anything like it. I just wan to have a URL that points to a file stored on a repository.

Perhaps I don't know if possible through CMIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct http link, but I did the following I've implemented a servlet that uses the Apache Chemistry's method getContentStream of documents, and wrote that input stream to the response of the servlet.

Comment: This method doesn't give a URL thus doesn't answer the question.